# Foxit Reader sideways scroll

Tags: keyboard, scrolling

**How can I scroll the document sideways using keyboard?**
As soon as I press the left or right arrow, it moves to previous or next page. While reading (as in adobe reader), these keys should help read the current page. Using mouse for this simple functionality is just not desired.

Any suggestions...??

Answer (score 3):

Shift key works as scroll lock in Foxit reader.

Answer (score -2):

shift + left key
shift + right key

Comment: This may answer the question, but this answer would be greatly improved if you spent at least a sentence or two explain what this does.